# PushViewController and UIView animation is invalid

Tags: ios, objective-c, pushviewcontroller

Recent project has a problem，when i push a View Controller, the `NextViewContrller` called `ViewWillAppear` but `ViewDidAppear` isn't called, so the NextViewController did not appear, When i make app background the `NextViewController` called `ViewDidAppear` so as I open the app again, the `NextViewController` appeared, A more amazing thing is that after that All my UIView animation is invalid
Note: invalid means that When i make a UIView animation, It does noting and as I mentioned I should make app background and open again, I could see the end status of animation

Answer (score 0):

Your description of what you are doing is somewhat unusual. viewWillAppear is seldom called.

My suggestion is to take whatever it is you are doing in viewWillAppear and load it into viewDidLoad. Remove viewWillAppear entirely. Then breakpoint the first instruction in viewDidLoad, and single step until you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks god that I have found the problem, It's almost about My navigationController `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` problem